# Transforming jQuery plugin to AngularJS directive - how to apply if/else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make this part of the jQuery in to an AngularJS directive

> ```
>       jQuery('#contentpanel').layout(             {
>             center__paneSelector: "#centerpanel"
>           , west__size: 200
>           , west__paneSelector: "#westpanel"
>           , west__resizable: true
>           , center__onresize: function () {
>               if (bpOrgEditor != null) {
>                   jQuery("#centerpanel").bpOrgEditor("update");
>               }
>           }           });
> ```

I stuffed this in to an HTML attribute so that it looks as such

```
content-panel="{
               center__paneSelector: '#centerpanel',
               west__size:'200',
               west__paneSelector: '#westpanel',
               west__resizable: 'true'
              }"
```

and the directive in angular looks like this

```
 app.directive("contentPanel", function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        jQuery(element).layout(scope.$eval(attrs.contentPanel));
    }; 
 });
```

but as we can see in the first part of this post, the jQuery also has an if/else statement, how can I inject in the HTML bit or do I have to do it in the directive its self? If so - how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `bpOrgEditor` is global and `center__onresize` option will allways be set to that function when using that directive, you can try:

```
app.directive("contentPanel", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       var opts = scope.$eval(attrs.contentPanel);
       opts.center__onresize = function () {
           if (bpOrgEditor != null) {
               jQuery(opts.center__paneSelector).bpOrgEditor("update");
           }
       }
       jQuery(element).layout(opts);
   }; 
});
```

And you can just write `200` and `true` in `content-panel="..."`, not `'200'` and `'true'`